# Unexpected token error thrown by JSON parse

Tags: javascript, json, mastercard

Need some help in figuring out this JSON.parse error which throws when the page loads.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()

This is just a sample code provided in Mastercard payment gateway [documentation](https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html). I am trying to test it with test data provided by the merchant. I ran the code through a validator and it doesn't return any errors.

Here is the code I'm trying to execute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/52/checkout.js"
                data-error="errorCallback"
                data-cancel="cancelCallback">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function errorCallback(error) {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
            function cancelCallback() {
                  console.log('Payment cancelled');
            }

            Checkout.configure({
                "merchant" : "TEST",
                "order" : {
                    "amount" : 1000,
                    "currency" : "USD",
                    "description" : "Ordered goods" ,
                    "id" : 123 
                },
                "interaction" : {
                    "operation" : "AUTHORIZE", 
                    "merchant" : {
                        "name" : "ABC Hotel" ,
                        "address" : {
                            "line1" : "some road" ,
                            "line2" : "some city"          
                        }    
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <input type="button" value="Pay with Lightbox" onclick="Checkout.showLightbox();" />
        <input type="button" value="Pay with Payment Page" onclick="Checkout.showPaymentPage();" />
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: should you be using this $(document).ready before making the js call to checkout.configure?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time when `JSON.parse` throws an error with invalid JSON at position 0 the problem is the `Byte Order Mark (BOM)` ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

To avoid parsing the BOM, you should check if the JSON string starts with `0xFEFF` which is the Unicode representation for `BOM` and then cut it manually off.

Example:

```
let json = `{"hello":"world"}`;

// make sure you trim the JSON string before, otherwise the first character may be a whitespace
if (json.trim().charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
    json = json.slice(1); // cut the BOM character
}

const result = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Tried this and it seems like it doesn't detect any BOM characters https://jsfiddle.net/hasintha/xm0z8u23/7/

Comment: But your example doesn't have the problem you have in your question ("invalid JSON at position 0). 

The BOM is delivered when you get data from a backend API or from a file on a server. It always depends which encoding the API or a file is using.

In your example the data is written as a string liteal so it doesn't contain the BOM.

Comment: Yes,this is a hardcoded string. What else could possibly cause this error?

Comment: When the problem occures with hardcoded JSON there must be a hidden, invisible special character or just invalid JSON syntax.